# smallest gps out there

Tags: microcontroller, gps

I'm working on a school project and my team needs the smallest GPS possible. With some help from stackoverflow, we found https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11571 from sparkfun.

This is good enough to prototype, but we were wondering if smaller GPS's exist out there just for knowledge's sake.

Comment: "The smallest GPS possible _for our project_". What are the requirements?

Comment: The requirements are that we can poll it for long/lat and hopefully it has decent battery life. Thanks!

Comment: You should add the requirements to your question. Decent battery life. What's the max current? What information do you need? How small should it be? Etc. etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can use component level GPS, There are smaller modules from [Trimble](http://www.trimble.com) (Zelia), from [OriginGPS](http://www.origingps.com) (14xx and the 44xx).
However, all such modules will require a PCB design. The smallest one is ~5x5mm, but does not include an antenna.